# mysql, only returning results greater than 10000

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am comparing the absolute difference between two tables, rounded to the nearest hundreds. I need the resulting output to only show values that are greater than 10,000. My output keeps including lower numbers. Here is my code:

```
select  ve.Geography, 
round(abs(ce.2010 - ve.2010), -2) as '2010', 
round(abs(ce.2011 - ve.2011), -2) as '2011', 
round(abs(ce.2012 - ve.2012), -2) as '2012', 
round(abs(ce.2013 - ve.2013), -2) as '2013', 
round(abs(ce.2014 - ve.2014), -2) as '2014', 
round(abs(ce.2015 - ve.2015), -2) as '2015' 
from ve join ce on ve.Geography = ce.Geography 
where 
ve.Geography = ce.Geography or
round(abs(ce.2010 - ve.2010), -2)>= 10000 or
round(abs(ce.2011 - ve.2011), -2)>=10000 or 
round(abs(ce.2012 - ve.2012), -2)>=10000 or
round(abs(ce.2013 - ve.2013), -2)>=10000 or
round(abs(ce.2014 - ve.2014), -2)>=10000 or
round(abs(ce.2015 - ve.2015), -2)>=10000
;
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use only '2010' and why are you using the first where-clause?

Comment: You already connected those tables with this line "from ve join ce on ve.Geography = ce.Geography" then you dont need to connect on where clause so you should delete "ve.Geography = ce.Geography or" first line of where clause.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
where ve.Geography = ce.Geography
```

This will always return true for every matching joined record in your result set.  Remove it, and the query should work:

```
WHERE
    ROUND(ABS(ce.2010 - ve.2010), -2) >= 10000 OR
    ROUND(ABS(ce.2011 - ve.2011), -2) >= 10000 OR
    ROUND(ABS(ce.2012 - ve.2012), -2) >= 10000 OR
    ROUND(ABS(ce.2013 - ve.2013), -2) >= 10000 OR
    ROUND(ABS(ce.2014 - ve.2014), -2) >= 10000 OR
    ROUND(ABS(ce.2015 - ve.2015), -2) >= 10000
```

Comment: Thank you! I ran the updated query but it still results in a table with figures less then 10,000. Is it because I am in mysql? should I try a different system?

Comment: Update your question and show sample data.  Your logic says to return a record if _any_ of the absolute rounded numbers be greater than 10000.  By which metrics are you saying that my query is failing?